# Express the polar equation in parametric form

Tags: trigonometry

$r= \sin(\theta)+2\cos(\theta)$
We did not go over very much of this topic. I do not understand the example in my book.

Answer (score 1):

To change from polar coordinates to parametric coordinates you can use this:

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}x &=& r\cdot \cos \theta \\ y &=& r\cdot \sin\theta\end{array}\right.$$

This come from the fact that $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ and $\tan\theta = \dfrac{y}{x}$.

So you would be left with

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}x &=& \sin\theta \cos \theta  + 2\cos^2\theta\\ y &=& \sin^2\theta + 2\sin\theta\cos\theta\end{array}\right.$$

Wich is a parametric equation where the parameter is $\theta$

You could also have $t = \sin\theta$ to be left with two curves that, combined, form the original one.

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}x &=& t\sqrt{1-t^2}  + 2(1-t^2)\\ y &=& t^2 + 2t\sqrt{1-t^2}\end{array}\right.$$

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}x &=& -t\sqrt{1-t^2}  + 2(1-t^2)\\ y &=& t^2 - 2t\sqrt{1-t^2}\end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

use $x=r \cos \theta$ and $y=r \sin \theta$ and find two equations in the parameter $\theta$.